# gtkmm Append_column(TreeViewColumn) display nothing

Tags: c++, treeview, gtkmm

I'm trying to color rows of a `TreeView` with different colors.
I found the following example online, but for some reason the columns doen't appear and the window stays empty.

I'm using `c++` with `gtkmm3`.

Here's the code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class Columns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
{
    public:
        Columns () { add (name); add (color); add(value); }
        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> name;
        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<int> value;
        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> color;  // a non-display column to store the color for each row
};

class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
        MyWindow() :
            liststore (Gtk::ListStore::create (cols))
        {
            // add some random data to the model
            Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *(liststore->append());
            row[cols.name] = "foo";
            row[cols.value] = 10;
            row[cols.color] = "blue";
            row = *(liststore->append());
            row[cols.name] = "bar";
            row[cols.value] = 20;
            row[cols.color] = "pink";
            row = *(liststore->append());
            row[cols.name] = "baz";
            row[cols.value] = 30;
            row[cols.color] = "green";

            treeview = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::TreeView (liststore));

            // create a view column for 'name' and associate the 'cell-background'
            // property of this column's cellrenderer with the value from the
            // 'color' column
            Gtk::TreeViewColumn viewcolumn("Name", cols.name);
            Gtk::CellRenderer* cellrenderer = viewcolumn.get_first_cell();
            viewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderer->property_cell_background (), cols.color);
            treeview->append_column (viewcolumn);

            // do the same for the 'value' column -- cellrenderers are per-
            // column, not per-row, so you have to do this for each column's
            // cellrenderer if you want to change the color of an entire row
            Gtk::TreeViewColumn viewcolumn2("Value", cols.value);
            cellrenderer = viewcolumn2.get_first_cell();
            viewcolumn2.add_attribute(cellrenderer->property_cell_background (), cols.color);
            treeview->append_column (viewcolumn2);

            // add it to the window
            add (*treeview);
            show_all();
        }

    private:
        Columns cols;
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> liststore;
        Gtk::TreeView* treeview;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    MyWindow *myWindow = new MyWindow;
    return app->run(*myWindow);
}
```

What am I missing? I checked using `get_visible()`, and the parameter is set to `true`.
No error or warning on compilation and execution.

EDIT:
If instead of creating the `treeViewColumn` and then appending it in the `TreeView`, I directly append the name and the column reference, it displays the column, but clearly I can't modify the background color this way.

To be clear, if I do this:

```
treeview->append_column ("Name", cols.name);
```

instead of :

```
Gtk::TreeViewColumn viewcolumn("Name", cols.name);
treeview->append_column (viewcolumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that helps me. Use [Gtk::manage](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/namespaceGtk.html#a753d0ddca83bd0d0decdfdcd1e93076a):

```
Gtk::TreeView::Column *xxx = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("Name", m_Columns.m_col_name));
m_TreeView.append_column(*xxx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about GTK but this looks dubious to me

```
        Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *(liststore->append());
        row[cols.name] = "foo";
        row[cols.value] = 10;
        row[cols.color] = "blue";
```

Try using a reference

```
        Gtk::TreeModel::Row& row = *(liststore->append());
        row[cols.name] = "foo";
        row[cols.value] = 10;
        row[cols.color] = "blue";
```

To me it looks like you are adding a row, but then modifying a copy of the row, not the one you added.

EDIT

Well having looked at the documentation, https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ListStore.html I think something like this is required

```
        Gtk::ListStore::iterator row = liststore->append();
        (*row)[cols.name] = "foo";
        (*row)[cols.value] = 10;
        (*row)[cols.color] = "blue";
```

Comment: I tried, but using row as reference give errors about binding and initialisation with liststore->append()

Comment: This modification doesn't give errors, but give the same result as mine